# Rails UJS: javascript file of ruby gem not available in Chrome network tab?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome

Rails comes with the [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) gem. In the `src` of this gem, there is a file called `rails.js`, which contains the functionality of the ajax. I have the gem loaded in my app and it works. I have the following in `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require jquery_ujs
```

However, in the Network tab in chrome, I see all the javascript files of my app. But when I search for rails.js, it does not appear. How could this be possible? Is the files of the gem precompiled by default? Is in a file with another name?

Comment: They are served as separate files in development by default. For production it does not automatically precompile them either. See the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development) guide for more info.

Comment: @maxpleaner I know they are served as separate files in development as long as config.assets.debug = true in development.rb. But that was not my question. My question is this: I cannot find this file rails.js in Network tab. Why not?

Comment: As a side note, reason why jquery_ujs wasn't working with remote: true in a dynamic data was not because the data was dynamically loaded via ajax, but rather because I had a form nested in another. And when the form is nested in another, the form itself will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the rails.js is compiled and merged on application.js. Try open application.js on network and with `ctrl + f` find this `jquery-ujs has already been loaded!`

**[edit]**

I create a new rails project with version 5, and I can see the rails ujs on network tab:

[see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McFq3.png)

Change this on your enverioment file:

`config.assets.debug = true`

**[edit 2]**

[Image with rails 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJMHG.png)

Comment: My development.rb environment already has config.assets.debug = true. And I am using Rails 4, not Rails 5.